# Getting an Invalid Syntax with datetime module

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, raspberry-pi

I am trying to do something which should be fairly simple with the datetime module:

```
import sys
import datetime
from twython import Twython

CONSUMER_KEY = 'omitted'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'omitted'
ACCESS_KEY = 'omitted'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'omitted'

api = Twython(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,ACCESS_KEY,ACCESS_SECRET)

time = print(datetime.datetime.now())
api.update_status(status='The power went out in the dorms again at '+time+'. Please fix. [tweeted automatically using python]')
```

I have chosen my time format based on the result of the 'print timenow' line however it says

```
File "twitterbot.py", line 12
  time=print(datetime.datetime.now())
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me to assign `print()` to a name but we can also see that the traceback doesn't match the code you posted

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, `print` is a special language construct and not a regular function. It does not return a value, so you can't assign its return value to a variable. You probably meant:

```
time = datetime.datetime.now()
print(time)
```

(Note that it's legal in Python 2 to write `print time` without parentheses, but I'd advise against that. Even if you can't use Python 3 (maybe you can, though!) it's good to get into the habit of writing code in Python 3 style to ease the transition.)

In Python 3, what you wrote is syntactically valid. But `print` returns `None`, so the `time` variable would not have the value you want.

Comment: It returns `None`?

Comment: @roganjosh Not in Python 2, thanks for catching that.

Comment: I suspect the error could be due to unbalanced parentheses in the code. The traceback does not come from the exact code they posted (note the space on either side of `=`). Maybe the jury is out for now

Comment: How would I have the printed time be in the tweet itself? When I try to put print(time) in the "" it still gives me the same error.

Comment: `print` is for sending text to the console (stdout), not to Twitter or anywhere else. To put the `time` inside a string, take a look at `str.format`. To convert `time` to a string, use `str(time)`.